# Visual Studio Debugging Help -- not detecting execution of a function?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm building a simple dialog system for a 2D RPG in Unity with C#. I'm having trouble with a certain bug where the textbox loops itself in some cases.

Anyway, the point is: I have a function that enables the textbox object.

When I put a breakpoint next to that function call, it is not activated. This would make me think that this function is not called. However, when I comment that function call out, the textbox object is never enabled.

Why doesn't that breakpoint get activated? Clearly, the code is getting to the function call... right?

Comment: Turn off optimizations.

Comment: Are you compiling with debugging information enabled and optimizations off? Do breakpoints work in other parts of the code? Is the red breakpoint icon in the IDE filled or hollow?

Comment: Is Visual Studio actually attached to Unity?

Comment: @Retired Ninja Yes, other breakpoints work. I think optimizations was the issue thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Had to turn off optimizations!